# Unknown problem with module using CV2 and mediapipe

Tags: python, computer-vision, mediapipe

I have some trouble running the module on python 3.10.1. This is my code:

```
import mediapipe as mp
import cv2
import time

class handDetector:

    
    def __init__(self, mode=False, maxHands=2, complexity = 1, detectionCon=0.5, trackCon=0.5):
        self.mode = mode
        self.maxHands = maxHands
        self.complexity = complexity
        self.detectionCon = detectionCon
        self.trackCon = trackCon


        self.mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils

    def FindHands(self, img, draw = True):
        imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        results = self.hands.process(imgRGB)
        landmarks = results.multi_hand_landmarks
        #print(results.multi_hand_landmarks)
        if landmarks:
        
            for handLms in landmarks:
                if draw:
                    self.mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img,
                                               handLms,
                                               self.mpHands.HAND_CONNECTIONS)
        return img   
                      
                
                
            #for id, lm in enumerate(handLms.landmark):
                #print(id,lm)
            #    height, width, c = img.shape
            #    cx, cy = int(lm.x*width), int(lm.y*height)
            #    print(id, ", x=",cx, ", y=",cy)
            #    if id%10 == 0:
            #        cv2.circle(img, (cx,cy), 8, (255,0,255), cv2.FILLED)
        



def main():
    pTime = 0
    cTime = 0
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
    detector = handDetector()
    while True:
        success, img = cap.read()
        img = detector.FindHands(img)
        cTime = time.time()
        fps = 1/(cTime-pTime)
        pTime = cTime
        cv2.putText(img, str(int(fps)), (10,70),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3,(255,0,255), 3)
        cv2.imshow("Image",img)
        cv2.waitKey(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It returns me the following traceback:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Eduardo.PC\Documents\UNAM 2020-24\COMPU\HandTracker\HandTrackModule.py", line 65, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Eduardo.PC\Documents\UNAM 2020-24\COMPU\HandTracker\HandTrackModule.py", line 55, in main
    img = detector.FindHands(img)
  File "C:\Users\Eduardo.PC\Documents\UNAM 2020-24\COMPU\HandTracker\HandTrackModule.py", line 21, in FindHands
    imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.4) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

I'm following a youtube online course for computer vision [linked here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=01sAkU_NvOY). At around the 30 minute mark, the module presented above is added. I pretty much copied it and it doesn't work. What's happening?

Thanks and sorry for the long post

Comment: please post the traceback so it's *readable*. [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70344135/edit) your post to change it.

Comment: `if not success: break`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import mediapipe as mp
import cv2
import time

class handDetector:

    
    def __init__(self, mode=False, maxHands=2, complexity = 1, detectionCon=0.5, trackCon=0.5):
        self.mode = mode
        self.maxHands = maxHands
        self.complexity = complexity
        self.detectionCon = detectionCon
        self.trackCon = trackCon


        self.mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils

    def FindHands(self, img, draw = True):
        imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        results = self.hands.process(imgRGB)
        landmarks = results.multi_hand_landmarks
        #print(results.multi_hand_landmarks)
        if landmarks:
        
            for handLms in landmarks:
                if draw:
                    self.mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img,
                                               handLms,
                                               self.mpHands.HAND_CONNECTIONS)
        return img   
                      
                
                
            #for id, lm in enumerate(handLms.landmark):
                #print(id,lm)
            #    height, width, c = img.shape
            #    cx, cy = int(lm.x*width), int(lm.y*height)
            #    print(id, ", x=",cx, ", y=",cy)
            #    if id%10 == 0:
            #        cv2.circle(img, (cx,cy), 8, (255,0,255), cv2.FILLED)
        



def main():
    pTime = 0
    cTime = 0
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
    detector = handDetector()
    while True:
        success, img = cap.read()
        if not success:
            break
        img = detector.FindHands(img)
        cTime = time.time()
        fps = 1/(cTime-pTime)
        pTime = cTime
        cv2.putText(img, str(int(fps)), (10,70),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3,(255,0,255), 3)
        cv2.imshow("Image",img)
        cv2.waitKey(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```